# Parameterised DataTable Split

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, .net-3.0

I wrote a method for splitting a DataTable into multiple small data tables; however I am getting exception. How do I correct it? Please share the code.

Exception message:

> This row already belongs to another table.

Framework: .Net 3.0

```
private static List<DataTable> SplitDataTable(DataTable dt, int size)
{
    List<DataTable> split = new List<DataTable>();
    DataTable current = dt.Clone();
    int iterator = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        iterator = iterator + 1;
        if (iterator == size)
        {
            current = dt.Clone();
            split.Add(current);
            iterator = 0;
        }
        current.Rows.Add(dr);
        //Exception: This row already belongs to another table.
    }
    return split;
}
```

Client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("TEST", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("VAL", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(0,"a");
    dt.Rows.Add(1,"b");
    dt.Rows.Add(2,"c");
    dt.Rows.Add(3,"d");

    List<DataTable> split = SplitDataTable(dt, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dt.Copy();` instead of `dt.Clone();`

Answer (score 1):

Before you add a `DataRow` to your cloned datatable, you need to remove it from the original source datatable:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   iterator = iterator + 1;

   if (iterator == size)
   {
      current = dt.Clone();
      split.Add(current);
      iterator = 0;
   }

   dt.Rows.Remove(dr);   // remove it from the source FIRST, then add it to the cloned DataTable
   current.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `current.ImportRow(dr);` instead of `current.Rows.Add(dr);`

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the DataRow from the source DataTable or create a new DataRow and add it to the new DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the line where you add the data row to current data table. Use the overload which takes an object array to create a new row. This way you are not cloning or copying any rows, instead creating a new row.

```
current.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will not work properly  try this 
I make some modification on you code it's working fine

```
private static List<DataTable> SplitDataTable(DataTable dt, int size)
{
    List<DataTable> split = new List<DataTable>();
    DataTable current = dt.Clone();

    int iterator1 = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (current.Rows.Count < size)
        {
            current.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

        }
        if (current.Rows.Count == size)
        {
            iterator1= iterator1+size;
            split.Add(current);
            current = dt.Clone();
        }
    }
    if (iterator1 < dt.Rows.Count) { split.Add(current); }
    return split;
}
```

happy codding